# Products disappear from Magento admin area and front end

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I'm working on Magento 1.9. Let the product Qty in the admin area is 1. And I ordered the product from frontend and now the qty became 0. Then the item completely disappears from the back end. On refreshing the product page in the admin area which I have already taken in my browser, will show the message "This product no longer exists". Product is not appearing in frontend too when I search the same. I can't access the item in the backend. Anyone has the solution for this?

The product can't be found in 'catalog_product_entity' table. But it's there in the 'sales_flat_order_item' table

Comment: check again after clearing cache and reindexing.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Already cleared the cache and re-indexed. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue happens because of your custom module.

This is not default bug. If I were on your place I would find `event observer`

and check the codes while they are deleting something or not.

In your case I think the problem is with the `sales_order_place_after` event(I think)

find this event in your custom module (Community or local) code pool and check the codes for that..

May be this is the only way you can get the solution

Comment: The product found in the sales_flat_order_item table.

Comment: @sree becuase order is placed after that item is deleted.

Comment: But I didn't create any custom module. It was properly working before. The event you are telling found in the MDN module inside community folder. and also in the Ebay import

Comment: OK so please check those modules code if they delete product or not

Answer (score 1):

This may cause due to any `extensions` or `module` used that relates with `Order`. When you place order the event `<sales_order_place_after>` calls the observer with certain function that writes product delete code.

What you can do is:

1. Search `<sales_order_place_after>` event in `config.xml` of your module
   or extension used.
2. Check the method which is dispatched by observer of `<sales_order_place_after>` event.
3. `var_dump` what that method returns.